# Why is Java printing a char as an integer?

Tags: java, types

I am writing a basic Java code to do an inorder traversal of a binary tree.

```
void inorder()
    {
        Stack<NodeT> stack = new Stack<>();
        
        NodeT current = this.root;
        
        while(!(current == null && stack.empty()))
        {
            if(current == null)
            {
                current = stack.peek().getRight();
                System.out.print((char)stack.pop().getData());//HERE
            }
            else
            {
                stack.push(current);
                current = current.getLeft();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Why do I have to typecast it to char?
The popped item from the stack is a node of the tree and in the same line I am calling `getData()` to print the char.
It's printing the ASCII value I suppose.

Edit:

```
class NodeT
{
    private NodeT left;
    private NodeT right;
    private char data;
    
    NodeT()
    {
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.data = '@';
    }
    
    NodeT getLeft()
    {
        return this.left;
    }
    
    NodeT getRight()
    {
        return this.right;
    }
    
    int getData()
    {
        return this.data;
    }
    
    void setLeft(NodeT ref)
    {
        this.left = ref;
    }
    
    void setRight(NodeT ref)
    {
        this.right = ref;
    }
    
    void setData(char element)
    {
        this.data = element;
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the NodeT class look like? Posting that would help

Comment: When you call getData() from the NodeT class, it's most likely a char as it's return type, and you have to cast it to a char in order for it to be called properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class NodeT
{
    private int val;
    NodeT left;
    NodeT right;

    public NodeT(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public void setData(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
    public int getData()
    {
        return this.val;
    }
    
    //however you defined getRight, and getLeft
}

void inorder()
{
    Stack<NodeT> stack = new Stack<>();

    NodeT current = this.root;

    while(!(current == null && stack.empty()))
    {
        if(current == null)
        {
            current = stack.peek().getRight();
            System.out.print(stack.pop().getData());//HERE
        }
        else
        {
            stack.push(current);
            current = current.getLeft();
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The above will work, because in the getter of the NodeT class, you have it's return type as int. All you'd have to do is plug in what you defined getRight(), and getLeft() to be.

Comment: Thank you. That was so silly.

Comment: No problem! Sometimes all it takes is a second pair of eyes